# Build Always On with TDE encryption using EKM Asymmetric Key

Tags: sql, tde, key-management

We are trying to create HA Group using the always on feature .

Our database is encrypted with TDE using an EKM (External cryptographic provider- HSM) .

When trying to build availability group through the Wizard you can not choose databases with

encryption key , I have found one link which uses T-SQL script to bypass this issue , but it uses

the master key and not an external key (asymmetric)

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/encrypting-your-sql-server-2012-alwayson-availability-databases/

Is there a way to set it up with EKM?

Comment: Google gives multiple definitions for EKM: "Extensible Key Management", "Encryption Key Manager", "Enterprise Key Management". Which one is it in your question? Because you seem to give it a fourth definition starting with "External ..."